# Usage of hyphen in German?

Tags: grammar-identification, interfix

> Die Nutzung elektronischer Medien zum Wissens- oder Informationserwerb ist in vielen Bereichen des Lebens auf dem Vormarsch.

Why is there an "s" and hyphen after Wissen in the above?

Comment: There seems to be a discrepancy between title and and actual contents of the question. The duplicate reason applies to the latter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hyphen functions as an [Ergänzungstrich](https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/Bindestrich-als-Erganzungsstrich):

> (...) zum **Wissens**- oder Informations**erwerb** (...)

which would be short for

> (...) zum Wissens**erwerb** oder Informations**erwerb** (...)

It is used to avoid repeating the same part of a noun. Works also the opposite way:

> **Informations**erwerb und -**technik**

Comment: The hyphen has since been edited.